# Module redefinition while linking static libs in two dependent frameworks

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linker, frameworks

Swift project I am working on has the following structure

```
   STATIC lib --- STATIC lib

        |            |

    FRAMEWORKA  FRAMEWORKB  

             \   /

              App
```

Where framework A and B integrate a 3rd party static lib with some headers, I have written a custom module map in Framework A & B

App on the other hand embeds FRAMEWORK A & B and naturally gets a module redefinition error

There are couple of ways I have been able to solve this issue

1: by weak linking (defining .a) optional as opposed to required in FramworkB project (although the feature isn't meant for this sort of hack I hear)
[image: screenshot]

2: Naming the objective-c module differently in Framework A and B, this way it tricks the linker into running the app successfully but I get this message during runtime in console logs

in 
FRAMEWORKA

```
module ACore {
    header "ACoreConstants.h"
}
```

in FRAMEWORKB

```
module Acorn {
    header "ACoreConstants.h"
}
```

> Class ACore is implemented in both
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TesterApp-anudhiavmakfclfdxilmgmfzordl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkA.framework/FrameworkA
>   (0x108ad2908) and
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TesterApp-anudhiavmakfclfdxilmgmfzordl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkB.framework/FrameworkB
>   (0x10881d908). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

is there a better generally cleaner way of doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling a bit, I evolved the architecture into a simpler one

```
     STATIC lib
           |
   Wrapper Framework
    /            \
FRAMEWORKA  FRAMEWORKB  
         \   /
          App
```

this way FRAMEWORKA & B talk to the an the wrapper framework through a facade and wrapper framework never has to leak information about the containing static library